# Adding a shared library and executable, compiling source files twice

Tags: cmake

```
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
cmake version 2.8.11
```

Hello,

I wondering if there is a way around the following issue. I have highlighted below:

```
SET(GW_SOURCE_FILES 
  module.c 
  module_imp.c 
  module_message.c
  module_config.c
  module_queue.c)

# Compiles the source files to create the shared library called dlg_gw.so
ADD_LIBRARY(dlg_gw SHARED ${GW_SOURCE_FILES}) 

# Link additional libraries to this
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(dlg_gw gc srl ${APRUTIL})

# ISSUE: Now I want to create my executable using the same source files. module.c is where my 'void main(void)' is. 
# However, I have some functions in there which will also be part of the library.
# However, this will recompile the same source files all over again. I don't really like that behaviour.
ADD_EXECUTABLE(sun_gw ${GW_SOURCE_FILES})

# After the executable is created, link the libraries with it.
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(sun_gw ${APR} driver dlg_gw dlg_sip dlg_ss7 dlg_isdn)
```

I hope you can see the issue above, as I am compiling the same source files twice. Once to create the `dlg_gw` library. Then again to create the executable `sun_gw`.

I was thinking of taking out the 'void main(void)' and putting it in a new file called runtime.c and then doing the following:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(sun_gw runtime.c)
```

But the above require me to change some of the source code.

Many thanks for any other suggestions,

Comment: Your fix seems like the right option to me.  Libraries shouldn't define the `main` function.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "OBJECT" library type introduced in CMake 2.8.8 can be used to avoid repetitive build of same files.

See http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library